# status=canceled in Chrome when loading an image

Tags: html, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog

I've a problem with Chrome on some computers :

- I've a loading dialog DIV in a web application.
- When this DIV opens using a [jqueryui dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), the request for an image (a loading gif) located in this DIV is canceled in Chrome (I see that in the network log of Chrome).

[image]

This problem is not reproductible with Firefox or IE.

Can you help?

Comment: You've provided almost no information, so it's difficult to give a meaningful answer... Perhaps a example could be provided? Or at least instructions how to reproduce it (like, code).

Comment: Hi Carpetsmoker, thank you for your comment! In fact, I tried to add pictures but I can't while my reputation is under 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make shure that your content expiration is disabled on the server. ie, for a microsoft IIS server, right click on the website and uncheck the content expiration button.